# position content to move up

Tags: css, vue.js, position, nuxt.js

[image]

Anytime I toggle the menu and for instance, it is the last row on the table, It gives added height to the container div. I want the menu div on the extreme right to move upwards somewhat like reverse the position to `bottom: 0` when toggled if its height is going to be longer than the table so that it doesn't give added height to the table when toggled, other UI library somewhat achieves this, but I have to do this from scratch

Comment: hello, show your code. Please read the stack overflow rule

Answer (score 0):

try use `position: absolute` in your dropdown class.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us understand better, please include a link and/or short explanation on why this helps.

Comment: @thunderCat7894, it's already absolutely positioned to that table cell